# Giant Elasticsearch query

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a list of must and must_not items that I currently have in a giant query but I want to know if this is the best way about the problem.

example of the query:

```
{"query":{ "bool" : { "must" : {"match" : {"tag":"apple"}}, "must_not": [{ 
 "match": { "city": "new york" }},{ "match": { "name": "pizza" }},...........
]}}}
```

I have 470 must items and 485 must_not items that are a whitelist/blacklist type of rules for data. The analytic is built in spark and the data is housed in elastic search. The query I am passing to spark is a query with one of the must followed by all 485 must_not items. As you can guess the query itself is rather large and takes around 2 seconds to return the results. I am submitting this type of query for each of the must items so therefore 470 queries passed. This application currently takes around 22 min to complete.

My question - Is this the best way to tackle this problem and is this even a good problem for elasticsearch at all given the gigantic query? I have previously attempted to preform spark joins with the data after just passing a query with just the must_not data, which takes far longer than the 470 elastic search individual queries. I used a broadcast hash join because the must data is smaller that the resultant data frame.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you need to distinguish between documents for each must/must_not case, then the only of doing that is to use separate queries for each case (unless you want to get them all and use lucene or other text search lib on the spark side to categorize them between the cases). If not, you can try to combine multiple match terms into a single match query (operator = or which is the default). But brings questions about having the same document matching separate cases so ymmv.

Comment: I do have a hash I am using to decide if there are results from the same document so that wouldn't be an issue. With all the match terms together I would want to use a filter right because must match would want the document to match all the match items at the same time ? You are meaning make the query larger into just a single query right?

Comment: so if you have 470 terms, instead of doing 470 queries, you can group them into 10- or 20- or whatever number of groups and use one query per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of the query involves following overheads:

- Query preparation and submission
- Spark - elastic search handshaking.
- Query execution on elastic.(involves index scan
  etc...)
- Serialization and Deserialization
- Network transfer.

The solutions proposed below will improve performance by avoiding some of the overheads(listed below).

- Query preparation and submission
- Spark - elastic search handshaking.
- Query execution on elastic.(involves index scan
  etc...)

If you don't need the separation of the documents resultant of individual query executions (470 musts), the ideal way is to build a boolean term using OR operator like @khachik suggested.

In the event you need the separation, two possible solutions

Solution 1 :

build the elastic query to return the scripted fields (and fields of your choice) having must_not in the matching criteria. In your case they will be 470 scripted fields one for each term , where each field is of boolean type. value will be TRUE if the 'must' term present else FALSE. Once result is cached as rdd, you may run multiple queries using filter of your choice. since data is cached in memory, the queries should be faster.

Solution: 2

First execute the query on elastic side with only must_not. Develop a function that returns "TRUE" given [TOKEN,TAG_VALUE]. Now append 470 boolean columns to the RDD using the function. Cache the RDD. Now you can segregate the data by running queries using simple filters.

Comment: Thank you, very nice explanation.